# Convert multivalue to single attribute in Solr

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

I have solr document like below (Using Solr 5)

```
{
"firstName": [
          "Jack",
          "John",
          "Darron"
        ],
"lastName": [
          "JackLast",
          "JohnLast",
          "DarronLast"
        ]
}
```

I want to convert this to

```
{
firstName1:Jack,
lastName1:JackLast,
firstName2:John,
lastName2:JohnLast,
firstName3:Darron,
lastName3:DarronLast
}
```

Comment: You need to write the logic for this and get it converted.

Answer (score 0):

Solr dont provide any provision for the problem you mentioned.

You have data in the array format for a field and you are are expecting it to get flat by solr.

You need to write a logic at the middle layer of your application for this. Here you can check the size of the array and then by creating the fields of array size and assign the values to it.